# cx_freeze python making executable file

Tags: python, executable

I do not know whether we can turn the python modules into executable file for window , and it can then write or modify a file in window (without the need of moving that file into the setup directories at the beginning).

That mean when I run the application, some text file in D directory  will be modified for example. Is it possible?
Thank you very much

Comment: you can always load it from an external folder relative to your "executable", so yeah, it is possible

Comment: Perhaps you could write a small program that modifies a text file and freeze it and see if it works both when running from `python` and when running the frozen executable.

Comment: @Netwave Hi thank you very much. Can you please give me some hint about the code or give me some reference link?. I have been struggling with it for the whole day but still cannot find the way.

Comment: @PhuongDuyenHuynhNgoc, let me know how is your directory tree to provide you an example please :)

Comment: @Netwave sorry for late reply but I have figured out how to deal with the problem. Thank you very much

Comment: @PhuongDuyenHuynhNgoc, thats nice, now please be gentle and share with all your solution ;)

Comment: well, the problem is not with the link as I thought, but the prolem is that cx_freeze somehow cannot copy numpy.core when running, so my program cannot run. I just need to copy it by myself

Comment: @PhuongDuyenHuynhNgoc, I meant that you could add a proper answer below, not just a comment, also some code example will be welcome. "Quid pro quo" on SO ;)